# convert jquery each function to pure javascript

Tags: javascript

I have script to show dropdown in select box. The script currently i am using is

```
jQuery.each( dslr, function( index, dslrgp) {
    var aslrp= dslrgp.aslrp;
    jQuery.each( aslrp, function(index2, pslrp) {
        var found = 0;
        jQuery.each( dropdown, function(index3, dditem) {
            if (dditem.countryname == pslrp.countryname)
            {
                foundit = 1;
            }
        });
        if (foundit == 0)
            dropdown.push(pslrp);

    });
});
```

How can i convert this to pure javascript. Because if i am using this

```
dslr.forEach(function( index, dslrgp) {
    var aslrp= dslrgp.aslrp;
    aslrp.forEach(function(index2, pslrp) {
        var found = 0;
        dropdown.forEach(function(index3, dditem) {
            if (dditem.countryname == pslrp.countryname)
            {
                foundit = 1;
            }
        });
        if (foundit == 0)
            dropdown.push(pslrp);

    });
});
```

it is not working.

Comment: "it is not working" — Define "not working". Give a clear problem statement. How does the behaviour you get differ from the behaviour you expect?

Comment: "convert jquery each function to pure javascript" — jQuery **is** pure JavaScript. There are perfectly valid reasons to want to remove a dependency on jQuery, but don't mistake jQuery for being anything other than JavaScript.

Comment: I have edited my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note the difference in order of arguments in native `forEach` - first is the value of item, second is index. So instead of:

```
aslrp.forEach(function(index2, pslrp) {
...
dropdown.forEach(function(index3, dditem) {
```

use this:

```
aslrp.forEach(function(pslrp, index2) {
...
dropdown.forEach(function(dditem,index3) {
```

Answer (score 1):

Your method signature is wrong.  It's:

```
arr.forEach(function callback(currentValue, index, array) {
    //your iterator
}[, thisArg]);
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Comment: what are arr, currentValue and array here ?

Answer (score 1):

You are using the `.forEach()` method wrong.
[forEach docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

You don't need to pass the array in as first argument. Just pass the callback.

```
dslr.forEach(function(dslrgp) {
  // do something..
}
```

or with key / value iteration

```
dslr.forEach(function(value, index) {
  // do something..
}
```