# How to rewrite in pure JavaScript code from JQuery code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, each

I have some trouble using JavaScript.

```
var $animation_left_right_elements = $('.bowl');

function check_if_facilites_in_view() {
    var window_height = $window.height();
    var window_top_position = $window.scrollTop();
    var window_bottom_position = (window_top_position + window_height);

    $.each($animation_left_right_elements, function() {
        var $element = $(this);
        var element_height = $element.outerHeight();
        var element_top_position = $element.offset().top;
        var element_bottom_position = (element_top_position + element_height);

        //check to see if this current container is within viewport
        if ((element_bottom_position >= window_top_position) &&
            (element_top_position <= window_bottom_position)) {
            $element.addClass('animationToRight');
        } else {
            $element.removeClass('animationToRight');
        }
    });
}
```

This is my JQuery code.

I checked this question [convert jquery each function to pure javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42157221/convert-jquery-each-function-to-pure-javascript), but cannot solve my problem.
I want someone can help me.
Thank you in advance.

**Update**

This is the code I tried.

```
var animation_left_right_elements = document.querySelectorAll('bowl');

function check_if_facilites_in_view() {
    var window_height = window.innerHeight;
    var window_top_position = $window.scrollY;
    var window_bottom_position = (window_top_position + window_height);

    animation_left_right_elements.forEach(function() {
        var element = this;
        var element_height = element.outerHeight();
        var element_top_position = element.offset().top;
        var element_bottom_position = (element_top_position + element_height);

        //check to see if this current container is within viewport
        if ((element_bottom_position >= window_top_position) &&
            (element_top_position <= window_bottom_position)) {
            element.addClass('animationToRight');
        } else {
            element.removeClass('animationToRight');
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. You might find reading the site [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and this [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). Code that you've worked on to solve the problem should include a [mcve], and be included in your question.

Comment: first line in vanilla js is: `var animation_left_right_elements = document.getElementsByClassName('bowl');` "EACH" iteration in vanilla js can be performed with a FOR loop: `for (var i=0, len=animation_left_right_elements.length|0; i<len; i=i+1|0) { /* code here */ }`

Comment: I updated my question with the codes I tried.

Comment: I don't know $(this).

Comment: `$(this)` is just `this`

Comment: I rewrote "$.each($animation_left_right_elements, function()" to "animation_left_right_elements.forEach(function()", but it doesn't work.

Comment: I tried that, but doesn't work.

Comment: you can also use `animation_left_right_elements.forEach( function(item) { /* use item here instead of this */ });`

Comment: @GrafiCode, what is item?

Comment: "item" is the first argument to the `forEach` function https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach (you can name the argument whatever you prefer, like `element` or `thisElement`, etcetera). Inside your forEach loop, `item` will represent the current element being evaluated.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Solved it. Please post your comments as an answer. I will accept it.

Comment: @GrafiCode `$(this)` is not `this`. `$(this)` is selecting the DOM object from `this`. You cannot do `this.off().on("someevent", function(e){});`. You can do `$(this).off().on("someevvent", function(e){});`

Comment: @Christian4423 of course you cannot use jQuery functions on `this`, that's the reason why jQuery wraps it in `$(this)`. But when you're converting jQuery code to vanilla js, if, for instance, you have to bind a click event on an element, you can use `this` inside the callback function, `this`  *is set to the element on which the listener is placed* https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#as_a_dom_event_handler

Comment: @Christian4423, GrafiCode's comment solved my problem!

Comment: Sato, when you reach 15 reputation points on stackoverflow, you will be able to self-answer your own question. I suggest to wait until you reach that target, then come back to this question and answer it yourself, posting the working code. https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: I got it. Thank you.

Comment: @GrafiCode, I answered my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@GrafiCode said it's good for me to answer my own question.
This is my answer.

```
var animation_left_right_elements = document.querySelectorAll('.bowl');

function check_if_facilites_in_view() {
    var window_height = window.innerHeight;
    var window_top_position = window.scrollY;
    var window_bottom_position = (window_top_position + window_height);

    animation_left_right_elements.forEach(function(item) {
        var element = item;
        var element_height = element.scrollHeight;
        var element_top_position = element.offsetTop;
        var element_bottom_position = (element_top_position + element_height);
        var video = element.firstElementChild.firstElementChild;

        if ((element_bottom_position >= window_top_position) &&
            (element_top_position <= window_bottom_position)) {
            if (!element.classList.contains('animationToRight')) {
                element.classList.add('animationToRight');
            }
        }
    });
}
```